# CommandError: errors happened while running msguniq

Tags: python, django

C:\Users\Boss\OneDrive\İş masası\ask>django-admin makemessages --locale 'en' --ignore=myenv/*
CommandError: errors happened while running msguniq
msguniq: error while opening "C:\Users\Boss\OneDrive\Is masasi\ask\locale\django.pot" for reading: No such file or directory

in main folder:

- locale

  - en

    - LC_MESSAGES

settings.py

```
LANGUAGES = (
('az', _('Azerbaijan')),
('en', _('English')),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'az'
MODELTRANSLATION_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 'az'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Baku'
SITE_ID = 1
USE_I18N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

and i use gettext 0.21 and iconv 1.16 - Binaries for Windows
in ubuntu server i can makemessages but in windows i only get error django.pot" for reading: No such file or directory,msguniq: error while opening

in django project i try to py manage.py makemessages -l en

Comment: Can you check [this](https://groups.google.com/g/django-users/c/DED6RXTFCwM/m/hfWLozCGV84J) pls?

Comment: I checked, but solution is not here. i dont think that it is conf problem, because in ubuntu server it works but in windows i cant makemessages. Thanks

Comment: Looking at your question, first like says `İş masası` but second one `Is masas`. Looks like someone is not handling unicode correctly. How about you change that folder name to something more sensible and try again?